# CLR Browser + Google Hangouts

Tags: browser, clr, google-hangouts

first post here so I hope I'm not breaking any rules.

So, the situation I'm faced with is a bit complicated. I'm basically trying to login into a hangouts call without having the ability to use the browser itself. I can only insert the URL. Why is that you may ask?

I'm trying to show a hangouts call on my twitch stream using a OBS plugin called CLR browser. This plugin only allows to rezise the window and add a URL from where it'll take information from. It's great for notifications but not so great for what I'm trying to do. But after investigating alot I came to the conclusion that I'm out of options.

I do know you can login to gmail by only using the url like here:
[How do I login into Google Apps via a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498083/how-do-i-login-into-google-apps-via-a-url)

If, for example I have a hangouts link like this:
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/gruxore63cq34fwddtcwwe64raa

Can I add something at the end so it logs in automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to disappoint, but you cannot auto-login using a link. OBS does allow you to screen share a window, though, so you should be able to open your favorite web browser, enter the Hangout, then share the window.

Failing that, XSplit has very flexible screen/region-sharing abilities.

Here's a [YouTube video demonstrating exactly how to do this in OBS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjzlmjjJ8jw&t=4m13s), and the link is time-coded right to the good-stuff.